# Getting type of array elements given the type of the array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am writing a generic function in TypeScript, and I can't find a way to extract the type of the array elements given the array type. 
Let's say I have some data like this:

```
interface Store {
    posts: Post[]
    users: User[]
}

const store: Store = {
    posts: [post0, post1, post2],
    users: []
}
```

and my function takes these arrays and does something on them, let's say return the first element when there's something inside.

```
function process<T>(storeItem: T[]): T | null {
    if (storeItem) return storeItem[0]
    return null
}
```

Now I want to create a new function that applies this function to all the store items in turn and create a new object. This function looks like

```
const processed = Object.keys(store).reduce((accum, el) => {...accum, process(store[el])}, {})
```

Now I want to define the type of the resulting object `processed` as

```
type Processed<Store> = {
    [K in keyof Store]: ArrayElement<Store[K]> | null
}
```

yet, I can't find a way to extract the type of the array elements given the array type, i.e. something equivalent to `ArrayElement` (this is something I made up). How could I get around this?

Comment: _"but the caller of my function is also generic"_ can you show that part? because I'm pretty sure `process<T>(data: T[]): T` is already what you need.

Comment: Actually you're right, I was just confusing myself.

Comment: @AlexWayne Hmm I figured that I still can't solve my issue, and my simplified example I gave was not addressing it properly. I reformulated my question to better represent my actual problem. Could you have a look at my revised question again please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types), in an example of advanced types.

```
type Unpacked<T> =
    T extends (infer U)[] ? U :
    T extends (...args: any[]) => infer U ? U :
    T extends Promise<infer U> ? U :
    T;

type T0 = Unpacked<string>;  // string
type T1 = Unpacked<string[]>;  // string
type T2 = Unpacked<() => string>;  // string
type T3 = Unpacked<Promise<string>>;  // string
type T4 = Unpacked<Promise<string>[]>;  // Promise<string>
type T5 = Unpacked<Unpacked<Promise<string>[]>>;  // string
```

So the simplest solution for my case would be defining my `ArrayElement` type as:

```
type ArrayElement<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : null
```